# insert data of selected gridview checkboxes values using c# asp.net

Tags: gridview, checkbox, checked, list.selectedvalue

I am trying to make a meal planner, I have a `GridView` of foods and their nutritional values and a `CheckBox` row. I want to be able to check as many foods as I wish. Then click the Add Food button and have the information of the checked rows inserted into my database.

Here is what I have which is not working:

```
 protected void AddFoodbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

       CheckBox rowcheck = (CheckBox)GridView2.FindControl("SelectFoodchk");
        for (int i = 0; 0 < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (rowcheck.Checked)
            {

                GridViewRow viewrow = GridView2.Rows[i];
                string foodid = viewrow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: And how exactly is it not working? Do you get an error message? If so, on what line? Or does it simply do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
{
   if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkboxid")).Checked)
   {
       //read the label
   }
}
```

[Looping through GridView rows and Checking Checkbox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743099/looping-through-gridview-rows-and-checking-checkbox-control)